# react-native link ENOENT: how does react-native link choose the path to look for .pbxproj?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

as per title my `npm install` command fails at the linking stage, throwing

```
rnpm-install ERR! Something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: 
no such file or directory, open '/Users/myuser/WebstormProjects/NEW_NAME/ios/OLD_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
```

Basically at some point i renamed my project via `react-native-rename` but it didn't have any issues until now, several days later, so I can't really trace it to the above tool.

**question**:
how does `react-native link` come up with the name of the `.pbxproj` file? It's looking for the old name, not the "new" one

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but in case anyone stumbles here I solved the error by running `react-native upgrade`, this time it caught up with the new project name...